# How to check if a String contains another String in a case insensitive manner in Java?

Tags: java, string

Say I have two strings,

```
String s1 = "AbBaCca";
String s2 = "bac";
```

I want to perform a check returning that `s2` is contained within `s1`. I can do this with:

```
return s1.contains(s2);
```

I am pretty sure that `contains()` is case sensitive, however I can't determine this for sure from reading the documentation. If it is then I suppose my best method would be something like:

```
return s1.toLowerCase().contains(s2.toLowerCase());
```

All this aside, is there another (possibly better) way to accomplish this without caring about case-sensitivity?

Comment: [DrJava](http://drjava.sourceforge.net/) would be an extremely easy way to test this when the documentation fails you. Just type a couple of test cases into its Interactions window, and you should find out.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. I don't think any of the solutions below are better than this. But they are definitely slower.

Comment: Your solution is simpler thant any of the ones in the answers

Comment: Your example is the simplest, most readable, and probably the best way to do this - better than any of the answers I'm seeing.

Comment: [*Does your code pass The Turkey Test?*](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Yes, contains is case sensitive.  You can use java.util.regex.Pattern with the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag for case insensitive matching:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(wantedStr), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(source).find();
```

**EDIT:** If s2 contains regex special characters (of which there are many) it's important to quote it first.  I've corrected my answer since it is the first one people will see, but vote up Matt Quail's since he pointed this out.

Comment: As stated by the documentation for `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, this works only for ASCII characters (i.e., "Ä" won't match "ä"). One needs to additionally specify the `UNICODE_CASE` flag to achive that.

Comment: is this approach using `Pattern` more performant than `s1.toLowerCase().contains(s2.toLowerCase())` ?

Comment: The first try it doesnt work then I changed  s2 <-> s1 , it works.

Comment: @GünayGültekin That is odd.  The code as given returns `true` and appears correct but if I switch s2 and s1, then it returns `false`.  Could you have your definitions mixed up?

Comment: Does it need less performance then toLowerCase()? Even in long Strings? When no, why should i use it? This method is "long" to write, too. For me it looks less readable.

Comment: @user01 I performed a speed analysis. See my answer for the results (I also showed a faster solution): http://stackoverflow.com/a/25379180/1705598

Comment: Using `Pattern.LITERAL` would be faster than `Pattern.quote`.

Comment: It would me more clear what was going on if we had better variable names: `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(needle), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(haystack).find()`

Comment: @user01 correctness comes before performance, and using toLowerCase will give potentially incorrect results (for example, when comparing certain Greek text containing the letter Sigma, which has two lowercase forms for the same uppercase form).

Comment: While you're right that it's usually better to be correct than fast, that's not always the case. I'm still hoping to find something both fast and accurate.

Comment: You can simply convert both strings to lower case like this: 
  string.toLowerCase().contains("someExampleString".toLowerCase());.

Answer (score 294):

One problem with [the answer by Dave L.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/is-the-contains-method-in-java-lang-string-case-sensitive/86832#86832) is when s2 contains regex markup such as `\d`, etc.

You want to call Pattern.quote() on s2:

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s2), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s1).find();
```

Comment: Nice catch Matt. I'm curious to know what method is more efficient - the lowercase contains, or your pattern solution. Isn't using a pattern less efficient for a single comparison, but more efficient for multiple comparisons?

Comment: The .toLowerCase().contains() method will probably be faster in most cases. I would probably prefer that style for lower complexity, too.

Comment: @AaronFerguson Yes, indeed, `toLowerCase().contains()` is faster. I performed some speed analysis, see my answer for results: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25379180/1705598

Comment: @MattQuail there's no point in it being faster if it may be incorrect. For example, the Greek capital sigma has two lowercase forms (depending on whether it comes at the end of a word or not) and when attempting to do case-insensitive substring match, where the substring ends with a sigma, you could easily get incorrect results.

Comment: I think we should add `Pattern.UNICODE_CASE` flag too. Could you please confirm this?

Answer (score 222):

You can use

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase("AbBaCca", "bac");
```

The [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) library is very useful for this sort of thing. And this particular one may be better than regular expressions as regex is always expensive in terms of performance.

Comment: Does anybody know if this respects locale?

Comment: @CharlesWood It delegates to `String.regionMatches`, which uses character-wise conversions, so no. Moreover, `containsIgnoreCase("ß", "ss")` returns -1, which is wrong in every locale (the German "sharp s" capitalizes to "ss".

Comment: Which would be the right way of comparing german words then? It seems that is one language that complicates every way of comparing strings :P

Comment: BTW: the German language was officially extended with a capital ß in 2017: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F. On German keyboards, type Shift + Alt Gr + ß -> test: ẞ 

Comment: Similar you may have the problem in capitalilzation/lowercasing the dotted & dotless i <-> İ and ı <-> I in turkish language (e.g. in İstanbul) vs. many non-turk languages using actually slightly distinct vowels for capital/lower cases I <-> i.

Comment: @stefan123t Have you tried to normalize the test before comparing? `java.text.Normalizer`. I admit it's annoying though.

Another thing you can do is to use an implementation of Metaphone algorithm. Maybe this one https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Metaphone.html is a good start. Even though, It matches "Istanbul", "ıstanbul" but not "İstanbul", "ıstanbul" nor "İstanbul", "istanbul"

Answer (score 144):

### A Faster Implementation: Utilizing `String.regionMatches()`

Using regexp can be relatively slow. It (being slow) doesn't matter if you just want to check in one case. But if you have an array or a collection of thousands or hundreds of thousands of strings, things can get pretty slow.

The presented solution below doesn't use regular expressions nor `toLowerCase()` (which is also slow because it creates another strings and just throws them away after the check).

The solution builds on the [**String.regionMatches()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches-boolean-int-java.lang.String-int-int-) method which seems to be unknown. It checks if 2 `String` regions match, but what's important is that it also has an overload with a handy `ignoreCase` parameter.

```
public static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String src, String what) {
    final int length = what.length();
    if (length == 0)
        return true; // Empty string is contained
        
    final char firstLo = Character.toLowerCase(what.charAt(0));
    final char firstUp = Character.toUpperCase(what.charAt(0));
    
    for (int i = src.length() - length; i >= 0; i--) {
        // Quick check before calling the more expensive regionMatches() method:
        final char ch = src.charAt(i);
        if (ch != firstLo && ch != firstUp)
            continue;
        
        if (src.regionMatches(true, i, what, 0, length))
            return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

### Speed Analysis

This speed analysis does not mean to be rocket science, just a rough picture of how fast the different methods are.

I compare 5 methods.

1. Our **containsIgnoreCase()** method.
2. By converting both strings to lower-case and call `String.contains()`.
3. By converting source string to lower-case and call `String.contains()` with the pre-cached, lower-cased substring. This solution is already not as flexible because it tests a predefiend substring.
4. Using regular expression (the accepted answer `Pattern.compile().matcher().find()`...)
5. Using regular expression but with pre-created and cached `Pattern`. This solution is already not as flexible because it tests a predefined substring.

Results (by calling the method 10 million times):

1. Our method: 670 ms
2. 2x toLowerCase() and contains(): 2829 ms
3. 1x toLowerCase() and contains() with cached substring: 2446 ms
4. Regexp: 7180 ms
5. Regexp with cached `Pattern`: 1845 ms

Results in a table:

```
                                            RELATIVE SPEED   1/RELATIVE SPEED
 METHOD                          EXEC TIME    TO SLOWEST      TO FASTEST (#1)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1. Using regionMatches()          670 ms       10.7x            1.0x
 2. 2x lowercase+contains         2829 ms        2.5x            4.2x
 3. 1x lowercase+contains cache   2446 ms        2.9x            3.7x
 4. Regexp                        7180 ms        1.0x           10.7x
 5. Regexp+cached pattern         1845 ms        3.9x            2.8x
```

Our method is **4x faster** compared to lowercasing and using `contains()`, **10x faster** compared to using regular expressions and also **3x faster** even if the `Pattern` is pre-cached (and losing flexibility of checking for an arbitrary substring).

---

### Analysis Test Code

If you're interested how the analysis was performed, here is the complete runnable application:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ContainsAnalysis {
    
    // Case 1 utilizing String.regionMatches()
    public static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String src, String what) {
        final int length = what.length();
        if (length == 0)
            return true; // Empty string is contained
            
        final char firstLo = Character.toLowerCase(what.charAt(0));
        final char firstUp = Character.toUpperCase(what.charAt(0));
        
        for (int i = src.length() - length; i >= 0; i--) {
            // Quick check before calling the more expensive regionMatches()
            // method:
            final char ch = src.charAt(i);
            if (ch != firstLo && ch != firstUp)
                continue;
            
            if (src.regionMatches(true, i, what, 0, length))
                return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    // Case 2 with 2x toLowerCase() and contains()
    public static boolean containsConverting(String src, String what) {
        return src.toLowerCase().contains(what.toLowerCase());
    }
    
    // The cached substring for case 3
    private static final String S = "i am".toLowerCase();
    
    // Case 3 with pre-cached substring and 1x toLowerCase() and contains()
    public static boolean containsConverting(String src) {
        return src.toLowerCase().contains(S);
    }
    
    // Case 4 with regexp
    public static boolean containsIgnoreCaseRegexp(String src, String what) {
        return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(what), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                    .matcher(src).find();
    }
    
    // The cached pattern for case 5
    private static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile(
            Pattern.quote("i am"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    
    // Case 5 with pre-cached Pattern
    public static boolean containsIgnoreCaseRegexp(String src) {
        return P.matcher(src).find();
    }
    
    // Main method: perfroms speed analysis on different contains methods
    // (case ignored)
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String src = "Hi, I am Adam";
        final String what = "i am";
        
        long start, end;
        final int N = 10_000_000;
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            containsIgnoreCase(src, what);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Case 1 took " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            containsConverting(src, what);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Case 2 took " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            containsConverting(src);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Case 3 took " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            containsIgnoreCaseRegexp(src, what);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Case 4 took " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
        
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            containsIgnoreCaseRegexp(src);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Case 5 took " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: +1 but note that it fails for `ß` (German sharp S; capitalizes to `SS`) and also for some other characters (see the source of `String.regionMatches`, which tries both conversions).

Comment: Your always tests the same strings, which is not really a fair comparison. 'i am' is always in the middle, which might or might not make a difference for the different search methods. Better would be to generate random strings and also report on the speed when a substring is not present.

Comment: That seems really close to Apache StringUtils method : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java#StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: @alain.janinm I fail to see the similarities. The only thing that seems "close" with `StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase()` is that both my solution and the Apache one use a `regionMatches()` method (in a cycle), but even that is not the same as I call `String.regionMatches()` and Apache calls `CharSequenceUtils.regionMatches()`.

Comment: @icza `CharSequenceUtils.regionMatches` just calls `String.regionMatches` actually. Anyway, my point was to give the info, that if someone is already using StringUtils lib he can just call it because it seems to be an efficient way like you prove it with you benchmark. If I was not using Apache lib, I would definitively use your method ;)

Comment: Clever. Is there any particular performance reason why you start searching at the end of `src` for `what` ? It seems that the most common use case for this function is with a search filter, and in that case the odds are that `what` will be at the beginning of `src`.

Comment: @MartinDevillers I start searching at the end so the loop can go downward. And I go downward because that way the condition of the loop will be shorter and more efficient (comparing to 0), and also so that no temp variable is required to store the end/last position.

Comment: OK thanks for you answer! I'm not entirely convinced that these benefits outweigh the drawbacks I mentioned, but at least it's clear.

Comment: I would bet that a significant part of your speedup is the single character test.  But if you're going to take the time and effort for that speedup, you should just use Boyer–Moore instead

Comment: You should try comparing moving up vs moving down. I suspect the performance consideration Martin brought up is more significant than comparing against zero. I tend to write for-loops initializing two variables,`i`, starting from `0` and moving up, and `n`, set to the maximum value, so it's held locally and not repeatedly fetched or computed from wherever. Contains most of the same performance benefits of starting at max and moving down to `0`... your stack is a few bytes longer for that one extra local variable is all.

Comment: Very thorough.  My take-away would be that they are all within a reasonable range of each other except for the un-compiled regex, so  whichever method you find easiest to remember and implement at the time is good enough, but avoid a standard regex, and that there is a fast solution if you identify this as a performance bottleneck.

Comment: In my tests it one was slow, very slow to compare on list interation on `Android` using a `SearchView` with `Filter` implementation on my `Adapter`

Comment: @icza can you add the apache StringUtils.containsIngnoreCase in your test case? I think it's easier for people here to understand yours is faster.

Comment: How is this better than the one line of code that OP mentioned where you convert both strings to lower case before comparing?

Comment: @Mugen This solution does not convert the strings to lower case.

Comment: Apache Commons `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase("AbBaCca", "bac");` uses this offering easy to use solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9560307/7878602

Answer (score 42):

A simpler way of doing this (without worrying about pattern matching) would be converting both `String`s to lowercase:

```
String foobar = "fooBar";
String bar = "FOO";
if (foobar.toLowerCase().contains(bar.toLowerCase()) {
    System.out.println("It's a match!");
}
```

Comment: Character case is language dependent, which means it will work on your computer but will fail for the customer :).  
see @Adriaan Koster comment.

Comment: @kroiz, that depends where the String came from. Comparing "foobar" and "FOO" will always match, however if you are comparing user-input information, or language-specific content, then you are right - a developer should be cautious.

Comment: Uppercase is actually a slightly better transform for this comparison with other languages (recommended by Microsoft for example)

Answer (score 21):

Yes, this is achievable:

```
String s1 = "abBaCca";
String s2 = "bac";

String s1Lower = s1;

// Keep s1 intact for print purposes, if needed.
s1Lower = s1Lower.toLowerCase();

String trueStatement = "FALSE!";
if (s1Lower.contains(s2)) {
    return "TRUE!"
}

return trueStatement;
```

This code will return the String "TRUE!", as it found that your characters were contained.

Comment: A big drawback of using toLowerCase() is that the outcome depends on the current Locale. See: http://javapapers.com/core-java/javas-tolowercase-has-got-a-surprise-for-you/

Comment: The question actually contains a better solution as this one fails for non-lowercase `s2`. Not speaking about such details like that this one doesn't compile and if it did, it'd return a string.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and it works:

```
boolean found = s1.matches("(?i).*" + s2+ ".*");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's some Unicode-friendly ones you can make if you pull in ICU4j. I guess "ignore case" is questionable for the method names because although primary strength comparisons do ignore case, it's described as the specifics being locale-dependent. But it's hopefully locale-dependent in a way the user would expect.

```
public static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String haystack, String needle) {
    return indexOfIgnoreCase(haystack, needle) >= 0;
}

public static int indexOfIgnoreCase(String haystack, String needle) {
    StringSearch stringSearch = new StringSearch(needle, haystack);
    stringSearch.getCollator().setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    return stringSearch.first();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I did a test finding a case-insensitive match of a string. I have a Vector of 150,000 objects all with a String as one field and wanted to find the subset which matched a string. I tried three methods:

1. Convert all to lower case

   ```
   for (SongInformation song: songs) {
       if (song.artist.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowercase() > -1) {
               ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the String matches() method

   ```
   for (SongInformation song: songs) {
       if (song.artist.matches("(?i).*" + pattern + ".*")) {
       ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use regular expressions

   ```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
   Matcher m = p.matcher("");
   for (SongInformation song: songs) {
       m.reset(song.artist);
       if (m.find()) {
       ...
       }
   }
   ```

Timing results are:

- No attempted match: 20 msecs
- To lower match: 182 msecs
- String matches: 278 msecs
- Regular expression: 65 msecs

The regular expression looks to be the fastest for this use case.

Comment: Good that you put timing results.  Everyone says how slow regex is, but in reality it's very fast if you only have to compile the regex once.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple concise way, using regex flag (case insensitive {i}):

```
 String s1 = "hello abc efg";
 String s2 = "ABC";
 s1.matches(".*(?i)"+s2+".*");

/*
 * .*  denotes every character except line break
 * (?i) denotes case insensitivity flag enabled for s2 (String)
 * */
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"AbCd".toLowerCase().contains("abcD".toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer by explaining how your code resolves the problem?

Comment: This answer has already been suggested in many of the other, more detailed answers to this question that others have provided. I don't think this answer serves any purpose here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your main question is here, but yes, .contains is case sensitive.

Comment: he is asking how to match case sensitive strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
String container = " Case SeNsitive ";
String sub = "sen";
if (rcontains(container, sub)) {
    System.out.println("no case");
}

public static Boolean rcontains(String container, String sub) {

    Boolean b = false;
    for (int a = 0; a < container.length() - sub.length() + 1; a++) {
        //System.out.println(sub + " to " + container.substring(a, a+sub.length()));
        if (sub.equalsIgnoreCase(container.substring(a, a + sub.length()))) {
            b = true;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Basically, it is a method that takes two strings. It is supposed to be a not-case sensitive version of contains(). When using the contains method, you want to see if one string is contained in the other.

This method takes the string that is "sub" and checks if it is equal to the substrings of the container string that are equal in length to the "sub". If you look at the `for` loop, you will see that it iterates in substrings (that are the length of the "sub") over the container string.

Each iteration checks to see if the substring of the container string is `equalsIgnoreCase` to the sub.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to search an ASCII string in another ASCII string, such as a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator), you will find my solution to be better. I've tested icza's method and mine for the speed and here are the results:

- Case 1 took 2788 ms - regionMatches
- Case 2 took 1520 ms - my

The code:

```
public static String lowerCaseAscii(String s) {
    if (s == null)
        return null;

    int len = s.length();
    char[] buf = new char[len];
    s.getChars(0, len, buf, 0);
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (buf[i] >= 'A' && buf[i] <= 'Z')
            buf[i] += 0x20;
    }

    return new String(buf);
}

public static boolean containsIgnoreCaseAscii(String str, String searchStr) {
    return StringUtils.contains(lowerCaseAscii(str), lowerCaseAscii(searchStr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class ContainsIgnoreCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String in = "   Annulée ";
        String key = "annulee";

        // 100% java
        if (Normalizer.normalize(in, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "").toLowerCase().contains(key)) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("KO");
        }

        // use commons.lang lib
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(Normalizer.normalize(in, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", ""), key)) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("KO");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use a simple approach and just convert the string's case to substring's case and then use contains method.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround :

```
if (yourstring.toLowerCase().contains("your string lower case")){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String x="abCd";
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("c",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(x).find());
```

Answer (score -2):

You could simply do something like this:

```
String s1 = "AbBaCca";
String s2 = "bac";
String toLower = s1.toLowerCase();
return toLower.contains(s2);
```