# Java: Comparing Array of Characters case sensitive?

Tags: java

I am writing a program to compare a few characters with a Char Array and return the index of the array. Is there any possible way to compare ignore case?
For example below:

```
String in = "I AM A HAPPY BOY";
char[] cha = new char[] {a,c,e,g,i,k,h,m,o,q,s,u,w,y};
char testChar = in.substring(4,5).charAt(0);

for(int a = 0; a<char.length; a++){
   if(cha[a] == testChar)
       return a+1;
}
```

I am unable to get the index as it will always point to 0. Is there anyway to ignore case here? Appreciate some advise.

Comment: Please see answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275004/in-java-how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-ignoring-the-case

Comment: String.indexOf instead ?

Answer (score 5):

Use Character.toLowerCase on both characters:

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(cha[a]) == Character.toLowerCase(testChar)) {
    // logic here
}
```

As a side note, you could get away with the first *toLowerCase* if all the characters in your array are already lower case, or even use *toLowerCase* on the initial string and avoid both.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Character.toLowerCase(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase%28char%29):

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(cha[a]) == Character.toLowerCase(testChar)) {
   return a+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Character.ToLowerCase(char c)` before testing for equality.

Answer (score -1):

in=in.toLowerCase();

However the most efficient way to convert chars between cases is to flip the 6th bit (ASCII values differ by 32).

Comment: Java does not work on _ASCII_. It works on [Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html). However 32 difference does apply to english alphabates.