# matching a word with other text

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making a program which takes users data to sign them up for an account.  For one of the parts, I want to make an error message for whenever their password they choose has a word in it similar to their username.  example:  `username = John`.  `password = 5john123`.  Error! your password cannot include the username.  I was looking through past questions and I found an answer that helped me. but only to a point.  The code someone suggested only made it so that if the password and username are **exactly** the same, then it would display an error message.   This is what they suggested:

```
if (Arrays.asList(password.split("[\\s]")).indexOf(name) != -1)  
              System.out.println("Error!  Your password cannot include your username");   
              else            
              System.out.println("valid password");
```

This above code only works if the password and username are the same.  if anything is added to either side it doesn't work.

How do I modify this so that no matter if there are numbers added on either side, it still finds whether or not the username is included in the password?  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how to check if a string contains a substring ( ignoring the  case )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275004/in-java-how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-ignoring-the-case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
String userName = "John";
String password = "5john123";
if (password.toLowerCase().contains(userName.toLowerCase())) {
    System.out.println("Error! Your password cannot include your username");
} else {
    System.out.println("valid password");
}
```