# Anagram Program to Compare two Strings

Tags: java, string, character, stringbuffer, anagram

I am creating an anagram program which compares two strings and am unsure how to go about creating a boolean that returns true if a character appears in both words.

My code is as follows:

```
StringBuffer strbuff1 = new StringBuffer(""); 

private StringBuffer strbuff2 = new StringBuffer(""); 

public Anagram (String s1, String s2) {

    s1 = strbuff1.toString();
    s2 = strbuff2.toString();

     } 

public boolean contains(char chart1) {
        return true;        //what do I put here? 
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I check if a string contains a substring (ignoring case)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275004/in-java-how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-ignoring-case)

Comment: Did you do any research? Have you made an attempt?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 1):

So you should be able to use the StringBuffer method indexOf.  Please check out the api documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Something like:

```
public boolean contains(char chart1) {
    if(strbuff1.indexOf(chart1) >= 0 && strbuff2.indexOf(chart1) >= 0) {
       return true;  
    }
    return false;      
}
```

However, I also think that your constructor's variable assignments may be backwards.

You probably want `strbuff1 = new StringBuffer(s1);`

This will create a new StringBuffer with the contents of the given String object.

Good luck!

*Edited to include a check for both words.

Comment: The method should return true only if the character is contained within both words

Comment: Edited to include this scenario.  My mistake for missing that requirement in the original posting.

Comment: Thanks.  Also, I went this route because StringBuffer doesn't have a contains() method.  Which it appears the original poster is restricted by.

Comment: Good point. I misread that portion of the code. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need

```
public boolean contains(char chart1) {
    return stringOne.contains(Character.toString(chart1)) &&
        stringTwo.contains(Character.toString(chart1));
}
```

This will return true if the provided character is contained within both strings, false otherwise