# Java if string in variable

Tags: java

very new to java, but I can't seem to find how to do this in java..

```
var1 = "testing101"
if("101" in testing) balala
```

How do I do in, in java?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;




public class Main {
    public static void buttonPressed(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.csgodouble.com/index.php");
        WebElement rollingTimer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"banner\"]"));
        if(rollingTimer :: "Rolling in 41")

    }
}
```

this is how I thought it was done..

Comment: `if(var1.contains("101"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I check if a string contains a substring (ignoring case)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275004/in-java-how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-ignoring-case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you trying to see if a string contains a sub string:

```
String var1 = "testing101"
if(var1.contains("101"))
```

Comment: Hmmm, is there something I need to import? says cannot resolve "contains"

Comment: @user6069863 What type did you declare `var1` as?

Comment: Nevermind got it, f(rollingTimer.getText().contains(""));

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use the [contains](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm) method of String class.

Answer (score 0):

For a String in Java to see if a String is contained in another one do:

```
String str1 = "testing 1";
if(str1.contains("testing"))
{
     //Add your code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, you can compare string for equallity check,

```
    if("Rolling in 41".equals(rollingTimer )){ // compare with case-sensitive

    }

    // OR this way also

if("Rolling in 41".equalsIgnoreCase(rollingTimer )){ // compare without case-sensitive

    }
```