# How to get the required string from a QR code scan Result use the ZXING Library

Tags: java, android, string, full-text-search, zxing

I have a QR code scan result, i would like to get a specific string from the result.

example: if the result is **"ROGS,Hudson,J'kobi,Anderson,Harrison,454242,SAM,HARRY, TIM, JOHN,SAMMY,TONNY,SAMON,GROOD,TOD."**

And i would like to get the name TONNY from the result string. What is the best way to go about this in Android Java code.

My Current code is as below

```
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here

        Log.e("handler", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        Log.e("handler", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
        alert1.show();

        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
```

Comment: Is the format of the string always the same as you have shown in the example?

Comment: Format is same. each name is always separated by a comma, but no of name will keep varying.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do a simple string match to check for TONNY or any other name?

```
String required = "TONNY";
String result = rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString();
return result.matches(required)
```

Edit : to ignore case

```
result.toLowerCase().contains(required.toLowerCase())
```

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275004/in-java-how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-ignoring-case)

Edit2 :To get the no., split the result and loop

```
String array[] = result.split(",")
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
   if(array[i].equals(required))
     return i
```

Comment: I will have a number attached with the names so is want that number also, that number will key varying