# Extract Name from ID Card with OCR Mobile Vision

Tags: java, android, google-api, ocr, text-recognition

I'm able to get all text from ID card with Mobile Vision API Text Recognition but I want to extract specific information such as Name, Surname from the text.

A block of output is like this:

[image]

Is there any way extract Name from the String?

or, Is there any API to do this job ?

I'm open to all advices.

Comment: You got it? I'm also wanting to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from here [In Java, how do I check if a string contains a substring (ignoring case)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275004/in-java-how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-ignoring-case#comment50033723_2275035) to acquire index where Name starts and index of Surname as end of substring. Maybe there is some easier way.