# Java Searching Through a String

Tags: java, search

So I want to search through a string to see if it contains the substring that I'm looking for. This is the algorithm I wrote up:

```
    //Declares the String to be searched
    String temp = "Hello World?";

    //A String array is created to store the individual 
    //substrings in temp
    String[] array = temp.split(" ");

    //Iterates through String array and determines if the
    //substring is present
    for(String a : array)
    {
        if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("hello"))
        {
            System.out.println("Found");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
```

This algorithm works for "hello" but I don't know how to get it to work for "world" since it has a question mark attached to it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean that "world" should match "World?" ????

Comment: Yes, I want it to ignore the question mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

```
String.contains();
```

To get a containsIgnoreCase(), you'll have to make your searchword and your String toLowerCase().

Take a look at this answer: 
[How to check if a String contains another String in a case insensitive manner in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/is-the-contains-method-in-java-lang-string-case-sensitive)

```
return s1.toLowerCase().contains(s2.toLowerCase());
```

This will also be true for:
war of the worlds, because it will find **world**. If you don't want this behavior, youll have to change your method like @Bart Kiers said.

Comment: `.contains()` is casesensetive, while OP uses `equalsIgnoreCase`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/is-the-contains-method-in-java-lang-string-case-sensitive might be usefull

Comment: You are right. But at the same location, you can fin the method toLowerCase(). But I'll fix my answer.

Comment: this is faulty in the case of `temp="hell worldie"` either `hell` or `worldie` (depending if `s1` is the user controlled string or the input) will produce true.

Comment: Yes, but it was asked for that, I think: 
    'This algorithm works for "hello" but I don't know how to get it to work for "world" since it has a question mark attached to it.'

Answer (score 4):

Split on the following instead:

```
"[\\s?.!,]"
```

which matches any space char, question mark, dot, exclamation or a comma (add more chars if you like).

Or do a `temp = temp.toLowerCase()` and then `temp.contains("world")`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to do this, it's already implemented:

[IndexOf and others](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/HasSubstr.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use :

```
String string = "Hello World?";
boolean  b = string.indexOf("Hello") > 0;         // true
```

To ignore case, regular expressions must be used .

```
b = string.matches("(?i).*Hello.*");
```

One more variation to ignore case would be :

```
// To ignore case
b=string.toLowerCase().indexOf("Hello".toLowerCase()) > 0 // true
```