# How to use contains and equalsIgnoreCase in string

Tags: java

Is there a way to check if a string contains something while not being case sensitive?

For example: (this code is invalid it's just for you to get a basic understanding of my question)

```
String text = "I love ponies";

if(text.contains().equalsIgnoreCase("love") {
    // do something
}
```

EDIT:
-------- Still not working

ooh, turns out it's not working. Here's what I'm using.
(it's a curse filter for a game)

```
public void onChat(PlayerChatEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer(); 
    if (event.getMessage().contains("douche".toLowerCase()) || /* More words ... */) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Midnight Blue] " + ChatColor.RED + "Please Don't Swear.");
    }
}
```

It works with lowercase but not uppercase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Contains Method in java.lang.String Case-sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/is-the-contains-method-in-java-lang-string-case-sensitive)

Comment: It's still not working because you havn't read the answers properly. If you want to use that style then read Anubhooti Pareek's answer again. You need event.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains(otherString.toLowerCase())

Comment: Also if you plan to filter out all bad words with them hard coded into an if statement you are going to end up with a very big conditional...

Answer (score 29):

```
return text.toLowerCase().contains(s2.toLowerCase());
```

Or another way would be

```
Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(s2), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(text).find();
```

Comment: I like the first solution. Very smooth :)

Answer (score 8):

It would be easier if you use [`StringUtils#containsIgnoreCase`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library

If you can't add a third party library, you can still use the code because is free to use. Check the [online source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java.html).

Test:

```
public class QuestionABCD {
    public static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String str, String searchStr) {
        if (str == null || searchStr == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int len = searchStr.length();
        int max = str.length() - len;
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            if (str.regionMatches(true, i, searchStr, 0, len)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(containsIgnoreCase("abc", "A"));
        System.out.println(containsIgnoreCase("abc", "a"));
        System.out.println(containsIgnoreCase("abc", "B"));
        System.out.println(containsIgnoreCase("abc", "b"));
        System.out.println(containsIgnoreCase("abc", "z"));
        System.out.println(containsIgnoreCase("abc", "Z"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative you have given if the OP does not want to add the third party library :)

Answer (score 7):

If case sensitivity is your only issue convert everything into lowercase

```
String text = "I love ponies";
String test = "LOVE";
if(text.toLowerCase().contains(test.toLowerCase()))
{
//your code
}
```

update:
for your code use :

```
event.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("douche".toLowerCase())
```

in all the conditions

Answer (score -9):

You can check twice like this

```
text.contains(s);
text.contains(s.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: This is wrong: `s = "aBc"`, `text = "AbC"`. [Both will be `false`.](http://ideone.com/Y2Zh6u)

Comment: i knew it was simple, i was just over-ly complicating it. lol