# Can we check if string contains in another string with case insensitive?

Tags: java, string, compare, contains, case-insensitive

I want to check if string contains in another string but in case insensitive manner.

for example - "Kabir" contains in "Dr.kabir's house.". Now "Kabir" with  capital K should find in "Dr.kabir's house." with or without spaces in this sentence.

I tried to use contains. But contains() is case sensitive, I also tried to use equalsIgnoreCase() but its not useful.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
        if (matching.contains(itemsList.get(i))) {
            item = itemsList.get(i).trim();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Also tried this by making string  uppercase but it checks for all the letters as Uppercase. I want to check if only initial letter is capital.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
        if (matching.contains(itemsList.get(i))) {
            item = itemsList.get(i).trim();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help with this please? Thank you..

EDIT : If I want to split "kabir" from the string how to do it?

Comment: duplicate of this I think, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972299/how-to-use-contains-and-equalsignorecase-in-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just lowercase both strings and then use `contains()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.size(); i++) {
    if (matching.toLowerCase().contains(itemsList.get(i).toLowerCase())) {
        item = itemsList.get(i).trim();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. But this checks for either all the lower case letters or upper case letters. but what if one word is uppercase and others are small like "Kabir"?

Comment: @Sid My solution, as well as the other answers, convert _both_ strings to lowercase, so the case no longer matters, only the letters.  Does this make sense?

Comment: as an additional, String is immutable. so It will not change the `matching` String unless you assigned the lowercase value to it.

Comment: how can I split "kabir" from the string? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @Sid You can try using a combination of `String#indexOf` and `String#substring` to isolate the string around the substring `kabir`.

Answer (score 3):

Just convert both strings to either lower or upper case first before using `.contains()` method.

**For example:**

```
if (str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase()))
    //do whatever
```

Comment: I have tried this. But this checks for either all the lower case letters or upper case letters. but what if one word is uppercase and others are small like "Kabir"?

Comment: @Sid It will still work, because you convert both strings before performing the match. So neither strings will contain any upper case letter before the check.

Answer (score 2):

make both strings lower (or upper) case

```
String one = "test";
String two = "TESTY";

if (two.toLowerCase ().contains (one.toLowerCase ())) {
    System.out.println ("Yep");
}
else {
    System.out.println ("Nope");
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. But this checks for either all the lower case letters or upper case letters. but what if one word is uppercase and others are small like "Kabir"?

Comment: this is making both words lowercase