# Case-insensitive indexOf working for Latin-1 characters

Tags: java, unicode, case-insensitive

I'm looking for a method passing the following test cases:

```
 assertEquals(0, indexOfIgnoreCase("ss", "ß"));
 assertEquals(0, indexOfIgnoreCase("ß", "ss"));
 assertEquals(1, indexOfIgnoreCase("ßa", "a"));
```

The funny character (called German "sharp S") is not really exotic (U+00DF, present in Latin-1 Supplement Unicode block), unless you capitalize it: `"ß".toUpperCase()` returns `"SS"` (locale-independent).

My search for a solution working for at least the *first 256 Unicode characters* returned nothing but ICU4j, which I don't want to use.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86780/581205) (indirectly) asks for a case-insensitive version of `String.contains`, but note that most of the answers work for ASCII only. The accepted answer can be adapted like

```
final int flags = Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(needle), flags);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(hay);
return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
```

so it works also for non-ASCII and returns the position instead of a boolean. However, it fails the above tests.

Apache `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` doesn't pass either. This [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25379180/581205) utilizing `String.regionMatches` provides a fast solution, but doesn't pass.

Converting to lowercase wouldn't suffice, converting to uppercase sort of would, but the last test case would return 2 instead of 1.

---

I'm a bit unsure about what the result of

```
indexOfIgnoreCase("ßa", "sa")
```

should be? `0.5` as the "needle" starts at the second `S` from the capitalization of `ß`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert original text and needle to char arrays
2. Convert each character to upper case
3. Find needle sub-array position in original text array.

For example:

```
char[] text = convertToUpperCase("...".toCharArray());
char[] needle = convertToUpperCase("...".toCharArray());

for (int i = 0; i < text.length - needle.length; i++)
    if (arraysEqual(needle, 0, text, i, needle.length)) // The same signature as System.arraycopy
        return i;

return -1;
```

Comment: I would like to point out that as far as Unicode goes, this is actually incorrect. Case-insensitive matching in Unicode must be done by comparing the case-folded version of the strings (as opposed to uppercase, lowercase, and titlecase version).