# compare first string in second string in android

Tags: java, android

if `String a = "ahmad";` and `String b = "ahmadkhan";` then, how to check that `ahmad` is present in `ahmadkhan` in start or in last. That is, how to check whether String a is there in String b ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Contains Method in java.lang.String Case-sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/is-the-contains-method-in-java-lang-string-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `startsWith` and `endsWith` to check whether some string starts or ends with another one.

```
boolean containsString = b.startsWith(a) || b.endsWith(a); 
if (containsString) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: And what happens if a is in b, but b does not start and does not end with a.

Comment: @LajosArpad Original question (it has been edited now and some intent has been lost) asked how to check whether string `b` has string `a` at start or last (end). At least that is how I understood the question. It does not ask how to check if string `b` contains string `a` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`contains`**

If `String a = "ahmad";` and `String b = "ahmadkhan";` , then you can check whether `ahmad` is present in `ahmadkhan` like

```
if(b.contains(a))
{
    //do your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b.indexOf(a) >= 0
```

is the criteria to be checked.