# What is the alternative for String.contains method that is case insensitive?

Tags: java, string, contains, readline, case-sensitive

While reading the line as a string from a file and string.contains("someexamplestring") will return the output of the case sensitive string.

If there is "someExampleString" in line, it's not returning.

How to identify a string in a case-insensitive manner?

Comment: Use a case insensitive regex, e.g. `string.matches("(?i).*someexamplestring.*")`

Comment: Regarding all the answers suggesting toLowerCase/toUpperCase - be careful if you go outside of ASCII space. There are some languages where going lower to upper and back (or other way around) is not consistent. Turkish with its dotless 'i' comes to mind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this is a duplicate of [How to check if a String contains another String in a case insensitive manner in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-a-case-insensitive-manner-in)

---

If you've simpler requirements and are dealing with English letters only, you can follow the below answer.

You should do `string.toLowerCase().contains("someExampleString".toLowerCase());`.

Read more about [`public String toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) from Java SE Documentation.

Also, as hinted by [`Artur Biesiadowski`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4210615/artur-biesiadowski) in the comment section of the question, re-iterating it here :

> Regarding all the answers suggesting toLowerCase/toUpperCase - ***be
>   careful if you go outside of ASCII space***. There are some languages
>   where going lower to upper and back (or other way around) is not
>   consistent. Turkish with its dotless 'i' comes to mind : [Dotted and
>   dotless I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I)

---

Also, to make it safer, you may use another method **`toLowerCase(Locale.English)`** and override the locale to English always. But, the limitation being you are not internationalized any longer.

```
string.toLowerCase(Locale.English).contains("someExampleString".toLowerCase(Locale.English));
```

Comment: Thanks @Am_I_Helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```
str.matches("(?i).*someexamplestring.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.toLowerCase(str)` method on your input String first and then apply `String.contains(str)` method.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve case insensitive operations we need to make both strings in one format either upper case or lower case .`toLowerCase` or `'toUpperCase'`methods will be helpful when you want to do contains operation

There are two variants in toLowerCase.

```
somestring.toLowerCase();
somestring.toLowerCase(Locale somelocale)
```

Example

```
String case1 = "StackOverFlow";
String case2 = "STACKOverfloW";
bool isSame ;
isSame = case1.toLowerCase().Contains(case2.toLowerCase());
```

> Note that  `equalsIgnoreCase()` will be helpful when you want to compare two strings

Comment: Please add your useful commands before downvote , so that I can know the correct answer. It will be helpful for learning

Answer (score 0):

You can `toLowerCase()` your String and then do `contains` with the lower cased version of what you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert both strings to lower case or upper case. Then do operation.

```
    Str.toUpperCase().contains("someexamplestring".toUpperCase());

                              or

    Str.toLowerCase().contains("someexamplestring".toLowerCase());
```