# Search for String case-insensitive

Tags: java

I want to search for any name in a text file. For example, the name is written as Emily in the text file.

If the user types "emily" or "EmiLY" the code should find the name Emily.

I need this code below to be case-insensitive. Right now it searches for Emily but not emily

```
(search.startsWith(name) && search.endsWith(name))
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: one trick is before matching change both string to either upper or lower case and this will act like case-insensitive check

Comment: I'm using java.

Comment: if i change the user input to all lowercase "emily" or all uppercase "EMILY", how will it find "Emily"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a String contains another String in a case insensitive manner in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-a-case-insensitive-manner-in)

Comment: When you ask a question, please remember to add the language (Java) as a tag. Also review [how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use the code you posted, you just push both items to lowercase and then do the comparison.

```
string searchLower = search.toLowerCase();
string nameLower = name.toLowerCase();
boolean isIncluded = searchLower.startsWith(nameLower) && searchLower.endsWith(nameLower);
```

Otherwise, if you're actually trying to find if `name` is contained in your `search`. Then you can use [`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) from the [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) library.

```
boolean isIncluded = StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(search, name);
```