# contains & indexOf not working with alphanumeric string

Tags: java, android, string, contains

I am trying to get a string between two strings but `contains` & `indexOf` method not working.

Please help me out if someone had the same issue.

Main String = [)>061PKDU 127 161/3R4C22PDUW 30 016D20110714STU8X195955

I am trying to find string **16D** but `contains` method giving me false & `indexOf` always returning -1

Please let me know if am doing anything wrong otherwise your help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Please have a look at the screenshot for more info,

[image]

Comment: [I bet on not visible char](https://ideone.com/XoMDWO)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/90780/10470378

Comment: @Selvin Please have a look on my screenshot what i am doing wrong? I am doing same but its not going in if condition neighter its giving proper index.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve] instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @khelwood I have provided everything... even main string & string as well which i want.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh I see `data = data.toLowerCase();` which may explain that issue even if it is commented out in your screenshot you might forgeted to undo that lowercase stuff elsewhere?

Comment: @Eritrean I just tried with lower case as well but its not working, thats why i commented it.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh I copy pasted your string and both `contains` and `indexOf` are working fine for me. You may want to `Clean Project` to delete all intermediate/cached build files or `Rebuild Project`.

Comment: @Eritrean Let me try your suggestion, FYI i tried same code in another class its working fine but i don't know why its not working in current class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution,

Main String = `[)>061PKDU 127 161/3R4C22PDUW 30 016D20110714STU8X195955`

This string showing me length 64 even character is 57, It's containing with `\u00D` character which is not visible.

So the original string is `[)>061\u00DPKDU 127 161/3R4C22\u00DPDUW 30 01\u00D6D20110714\u00DSTU8X195955`

So i have replaced `\u00D` with `""` now its working perfect.

Thanks guys for your help.