# How to replace text using ReplaceFirst() without case sensitivity

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a method which can highlight text in a `jlabel` according user entered search text. it works fine except it case sensitive. I used a regex `(?i)` to ignore case. But still it case sensitive.

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
        String SourceText = "this is a sample text";
        String SearchText = jTextField1.getText();

        if (SourceText.contains(SearchText)) {
            String OutPut = "<html>" + SourceText.replaceFirst("(?i)" + SearchText, "<span style=\"background-color: #d5f4e6;\">" + SearchText + "</span>") + "</html>";
            jLabel1.setText(OutPut);
        } else {
            jLabel1.setText(SourceText);
        }
    }
```

How can i fix this.

**Update**

`contains` is case sensitive.

[How to check if a String contains another String in a case insensitive manner in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-a-case-insensitive-manner-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not used the matched text in the replacement, you hard-coded the same string you used in the search. Since you wrap the whole match with `html` tags, you need to use the `$0` backreference in the replacement (it refers to the whole match that resides in Group 0).

Besides, you have not escaped ("quoted") the search term, it may cause trouble if the `SearchText` contains special regex metacharacters.

You can fix the code using

```
String OutPut = "<html>" + SourceText.replaceFirst("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(SearchText), "<span style=\"background-color: #d5f4e6;\">$0</span>") + "</html>";
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, and better explanation about html. but still got same result.It's not ignoring case.

Comment: the problem is `if (SourceText.contains(SearchText)) {` here `contains` is case sensitive. I'm going to accept this answer because of the improvement of my code.

Comment: @dins88 Your code in the question does not contain the code with `.contains`. Of course it does not accept a regex. If you need to find if a regex matches any string, you need to use `String.matches(regex)` or `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string).find()`.